# Compare array against object keys and maintain order

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to get data of each key from a passed in input array. Let's say my input array is:

`Input array: ['我','很','好']` (I very good)

And I have an object with matching keys for each of those, which all have more associated data.

I want to get that data back in the same order.

Unfortunately, the input data order may not always match the order the keys appear in the object, yet I need to maintain the order when I return the resulting key data.

Basically, how can I loop through an array (let's say `input array`) and compare against an object and return data against those matching keys in the same order?

**Object:**

```
var myObj = {
   "Foo": 
   {
       'wo' :  ['I/me','我'],
       'hao'   : ['good','好'],
   },
   "Bar": 
   {
       'xi': ['wash', '洗'],
       'hen'   : ['very', '很']
   },
   ...
}
```

**Get function:**

```
getValues : function (inputArray) {
        var result = [];
        for (obj in myObj) {
            for (key in myObj[obj]) {
                for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
                    //IE: if 我 === 我 
                    if (inputArray[i] === myObj[obj][key][1]) {
                        result.push(key);
                        if (result.length >= inputArray.length) {
                            return result;
                        }
                        ...
```

**Result**: `['wo', 'hao', 'hen']` (equivalent to 'I, good, very')

But result needs to be: `['wo', 'hen', 'hao']` (equivalent to 'I, very, good')

**Note**: I am using jQuery if that is of any help.

---

**EDIT:** What I could do is split the string initially, then loop through the length of the inputArray and call the `getValues` one by one.

The issue with this is, now I'm starting over looping through the `myObj` datastructure with each call, instead of calling once with a string of values and looping through the `myObj` once, adding each key as it scans down the list.

```
            var split = inputArray.split('');
            var resultsList = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
                resultsList.push(getValues(split[i]));
            }


getValues : function (word) {

    for (obj in myObj) {
        for (key in myObj[obj]) {
            if (character === myObj[obj][key][0]) {
                return key;
            }
        }
    }
    return 'not found';
},
```

This solution doesn't feel ideal.

Comment: what if both myObj.Foo and myObj.Bar have the same keys (e.g. "hello")?

Comment: @syazdani yes I'm aware of that. I'm eventually probably going to reverse the data structure, IE: `"Hello" : { "subject" : "Foo", "data" : ["a", "some data"] ... `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are searching through each key in the object instead of each position in `inputArray`:

```
for (obj in myObj) {
    for (key in myObj[obj]) {
        for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
```

should be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
    for (obj in myObj) {
        for (key in myObj[obj]) {
```

This way will ensure that it will find and add the order that they are **inputted** instead of in order they are in the object.

```js
    var myObj = {
           "Foo": 
       {
           'wo' :  ['I/me','我'],
           'hao'   : ['good','好'],
       },
       "Bar": 
       {
           'xi': ['wash', '洗'],
           'hen'   : ['very', '很']
       },
    };
    function getValues (inputArray) {
        var result = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
            for (obj in myObj) {
                for (key in myObj[obj]) {
                    if (inputArray[i] === myObj[obj][key][1]) {
                        result.push(key);
                        //stop loops if results list matches input list
                        if (result.length >= inputArray.length) {
                            return result;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    var inputResult = getValues(['我','很','好'])
    ,   result = '';
    for(var index = 0; index < inputResult.length; index ++){
        result += inputResult[index] + ' ';
    }
    document.write(result);
```

Comment: sorry, I messed up the keys. The issue is that I am actually passing in a Chinese character string, and need to get matching phonetic pronunciation as the value. See above edit

Comment: @Growler It's pretty similar logic. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$.each()` , `$.inArray()`

```js
var arr = ['我', '很', '好']

, myObj = {
  "Foo": {
    'wo': ['I/me', '我'],
    'hao': ['good', '好'],
  },
  "Bar": {
    'xi': ['wash', '洗'],
    'hen': ['very', '很']
  }
}

, res = [];

$.each(myObj, function(index, value) {
  $.each(value, function(key, val) {
    if ($.inArray(val[1], arr) !== -1) {
      // set `key` at `$.inArray(val[1], arr)` index within `res` array
      res[$.inArray(val[1], arr)] = key
    }
  })
});

console.log(res);

$("body").html(res.toString())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am misunderstanding the question, you can use inputArray[i] to do the lookup in myObj[obj] and get the result you are looking for:

```
var result = [];
for (obj in myObj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        var value = myObj[obj][inputArray[i]]
        if ($.isArray(value)) {
            result.push(value[0]);
            //stop loops if results list matches input list
            if (result.length >= inputArray.length) {
                return result;
            }
```

Comment: sorry, I messed up the keys. The issue is that I am actually passing in a Chinese character string, and need to get matching phonetic pronunciation as the value. See above edit

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over each key of your object (myObj) when searching for each input value:

```
    function getValues(inputArray) {
       var result = [];
       var arrayLength = inputArray.length;
       for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
          console.log('Searching for ' + inputArray[i]);
          for (var key in myObj) {
             if(inputArray[i] in myObj[key]) {
                result.push(myObj[key][inputArray[i]][0]);
             }
          }
       }

      console.log(result);
      return result;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this. Check the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0pg0Larf/)

```
var arr = ['我','很','好'];

var myObj = {
   "Foo": 
   {
       'wo' :  ['I/me','我'],
       'hao'   : ['good','好'],
   },
   "Bar": 
   {
       'xi': ['wash', '洗'],
       'hen'   : ['very', '很']
   }
}

function getKey(character) 
{
    for(obj in myObj)
    {
        var objVal = myObj[obj];
        for(innerobj in objVal)
        {
            var innerobjVal = objVal[innerobj];
            if($.inArray(character, innerobjVal) !== -1)
            {
               return innerobj;
            }
        }
    }
}

var resultArr = arr.map(getKey);

console.log(resultArr);
```